# Rails4: ForbiddenAttributesError on nested parent's params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, actioncontroller, strong-parameters

I'm still trying to wrap my head around **Strong Parameters** in Rails 4. I'm getting an `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` when trying to submit a form with params for another model that it `belongs_to`.

`Product :has_many DiskFiles`

After some sleuthing I realize that I need to symbolize my keys before passing them into something like this otherwise I'll get the `ForbiddenAttributesError`. So this will work:

```
#disk_files_controller.rb
def update
     product = @disk_file.create_product(params[:product].symbolize_keys) if params[:product]
    ...
end
```

inspecting params[:product]:

```
>> params[:product]
=> {"title"=>"Registration Test5", "year"=>"1988", "region_id"=>"7"}
```

in either case I'm permitting these params (among others):

```
def disk_file_params
  params.require(:disk_file).permit(:filename, :file_path, :title,
                                    :product, :year, :region_id)
end
```

Being as all params are initially `strings` then should we be permitting the `string` version of the params instead of the `symbol`?!? Not sure what's best practice here?!? I know the Rails 4 templates include the symbolized parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need to manually call `#symbolize_keys`. rails does this for you.
2. you can use nested attributes in StrongParams this way

   `params.require(:model_name_here).permit(:attribute1, :attribute2, :attribute3,
                                     nested_model_name_here: [:attribute1, :attribute2, :attribute3])`

so you can do something like this:

```
params.require(:product).permit(:title, :year, :region_id, disk_file: [:filename, :file_path, :title,
                                :product, :year, :region_id])
```

This is assuming that `disk_file`'s attributes is nested inside `product` for params hash. If you still get an error, please post a dummy app on github which reproduces this behaviour. so I can help you further. Thanks

Comment: brilliant; thanks! `:product` is the embedded model on this particular form so  `params.require(:disk_file).permit(:filename, :file_path, product: [:title, :year, :region_id])` worked for me!